# The reaction of Group 14 to get its full shell

Tags: periodic-table

I was learning about group 14 of the periodic table and in the course, on Alison (link at the bottom), it said a reaction of the elements in group 14, they use group 4, would consist of sharing electrons. They explained it to what I believe is from going to 2,8,4, Silicon, to 2,4,8 in order to get the full shell. I am very confused at how exactly that one works. But everywhere else, it was stated that the elements in Group 14 lost or gained 4 electrons. But the course said it wouldn't gain or lose any electrons. Is the course a bit more advanced than the others or is it just wrong?

Also, is it just called an electron shell or is there some other title for it, because shell doesn't really sound too scientific.

https://alison.com/topic/learn/17074/full-shells-metals-and-non-metals
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The content of the link appears to be inaccessible without registration.

Comment: Scientifically, it's "shells".  Bohr's model of the atom assumed the electrons are arranged in shells and that nomenclature has carried over even though the model is obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The course is probably wrong. Chemical elements of Group 4 have 2 lone electrons, but the need 4 bonding pairs with another element to reach noble gas electron configuration.So 1 electron from the other completed subshells moves to the p subshell and now we have 4 lone electrons. Once they all form bonds, the element reaches the noble gas electron configuration.

*The element absorbs energy in order to transfer an electron from a lower-energy to a higher-energy orbital, according to the lowest energy rule.But it is energetically favorable in the end since it reaches electron configuration of noble gas.